# How to use MessageType

Tags: discord.py

so I am trying to make the bot do something when the `premium_guild_subscription` message comes. I have tried:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    MessageType = discord.MessageType
    if MessageType == 'pins_add':
        await message.channel.send('ITS WORKING!!!')
```

but its not working. The above code does nothing when the message comes. If I do `message.MessageType` then it says that `message object has no attribute MessageType`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your code, you're trying to use class. You have to call the init function from that class. So you need to access a `MessageType` type data from `message`.

According to API References, you can use [**`message.type`**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.type) to access `MessageType` object. Then you can check if a message is `pins_add` type with `message.type.pins_add`.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.type == discord.MessageType.pins_add:
        await message.channel.send('ITS WORKING!!!')
```

Comment: says that 
`AttributeError: '_EnumValue_MessageType' object has no attribute 'pins_add'`. why?

Comment: This is completely wrong, you're supposed to check the type & compare it to see if the type is equal to the one you need, `MessageType` does _not_ have an attribute for every type, and they aren't booleans either.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an `instance` of a class and compare that to see if it's the correct type, not comparing the class itself to a string.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.type == discord.MessageType.pins_add:
        await message.channel.send('ITS WORKING!!!')
```

A further example:

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    print(ctx.message.type == discord.MessageType.pins_add)
    print(ctx.message.type == discord.MessageType.default)
```

Results in

```
!test
> False
> True
```